# Retreiving value from a element that is loaded on runtime with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, runtime, loading

So on my page I have one Div that I load all the content. I use Ajax to do so, like this

`$('#content').load('pages/'+ page + '.html');`

On every page I have a < h1> telling where you are on the page with the id=location. I'm trying to find that value and put it to the document title but it always returns "".

```
document.title = 'My page - ' + $('#location').text();
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the loading at runtime...
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right it has something to do with loading at 'runtime'. You can pass a callback to the load function which executes after the content is loaded. Try the following:

```
$('#content').load('pages/'+ page + '.html', function(){
    document.title = 'My page - ' + $('#location').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that in the `callback function` of your request..

```
$('#content').load('pages/'+ page + '.html', function(){
    // Your code here
});
```